# Calling @Autowired class from simple java class

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a java class
TestController.java - This is normal class

```
public class TestController {
  // Here i need to call controller class
  ExcelCreator excelCreator = new ExcelCreator();
  excelCreator.createExcel();
}
```

ExcelCreator.java - This is spring class

```
@Service
public class ExcelCreator {
   @Autowired
   ServiceClass serviceClass;
   @Autowired
   ExcelClass excelClass;
   public void createExcel() {
     // Code to generate excel file
}
}
```

When calling ExcelCreator from TestController class with new keyword, annotations are not working from ExcelCreator class, and if trying ExcelCreator class as Autowired in TestController getting Null value for ExcelCreator class,
I want to create a object for ExcelCreator class and generate data using @Autowired annotation

Comment: Use constructor injection instead of field injection. Then 'normal' classes can just create instances 'normally', passing an instance of `ServiceClass` and `ExcelClass` to the `ExcelCreator` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

TestController use **@Component** annotation,then try angin

```
@Component
public class TestController {
   @Autowired
   ExcelCreator excelCreator ;
   //use excelCreator do something
}
```

Comment: TestController is a normal class and I don't want to add any annotation to the TestController because this class is located in the normal package and ExcelCreator class is located in the Spring package...

Comment: use ApplicationContext.getBean("excelCreator ")